# cordova app on kitkat

Tags: cordova, chromium, android-4.4-kitkat, selfbrailleclient

i write a cordova application that run very well on android.
yesterday i format my phone with kitkat.
When i try to run my app on kitkat everything was wrong.
The css was not working (big fonts) the app was very slow and not listen to touch events.

From adb monitor i see multiple messages:

"chromium INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc[56] Async pixel transfers not supported"

"gralloc_overlay Self allocation gralloc overlay"
"SelfBrailleClient Failed to bind to service"

I tried to build with many Android API ( 14 , 17 , 19 ) but nothing.
Only with API 14 the css was good, but still the app was very slow and not listen to events.

My code is only js and html5.
Why everything goes wrong?
I see that the webview now is chromium.
Does chromium want something specific?

Comment: Any solution on this? I have very similar issues on Kitkat. But I am using the ionic framework. http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/errors-crash-on-android-4-4-2/11233